# Is it possible to remove salt from food without changing the flavor?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, food-chemistry

I love soup, even a thick soup for dinner, yet *many* soup products have 400 to 1000 mg of sodium in them. Is there a simple chemical procedure any consumer could do to take the sodium out of the product without 'hurting' the flavor?

If one takes some, say, Campbell's soup and heats it to boiling, then freezes it, then heats it again, then freezes it etc., would this extract some sodium?

Comment: Several brands offer low-sodium versions, but maybe you'd like even less salt that they offer?

Comment: I don't know how practicable it would be with soup, but size exclusion chromatography or dialysis can used to remove salts (although there would be no selectivity for sodium).

Comment: IF several brands offer low salt versions WHERE do you find them? Shopper's Drug Mart sells a lot of tasty foods in some of their stores but they generally have a salt content over 300 mg. for each product. THEY'RE supposed to be for health I assume. EVEN those Health Check product in  Grocery stores have over 400 mg. of salt for one person with one serving.

Comment: The salt is there FOR the flavor. Since most junk food like canned soups contain little if anything, their flavor is mostly coming from taste enhancers like salt and msg.

Comment: Thats going to be far more complicated than making your own soup. (Which is a far healthier and cheaper time killer than watching TV, so get at it! ;))

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Short answer: no, there is no easy (or even moderately hard) procedure, and certainly not boiling and freezing.

The thing is that water dissolves sodium ions better than just about anything else, so almost everything will come out of solution before the sodium does. You're much better off with a product that starts with less salt to begin with.

Comment: Could some safe substance be added to the soup that absorbs the sodium and doesn't spoil the flavor?

Comment: I've added a 2nd paragraph to my answer addressing that.  Sorry to disappoint you.

Comment: @user128932 To elaborate on Levy's answer, sodium very rarely forms any type of solid compound because of its solubility. There's nothing you can do to "absorb" the sodium because elements can't be lost. Your best bet would be to react something with the sodium ions that produces an insoluble solid, and then to physically remove the solid. But that's virtually impossible with sodium.

Comment: In truth it is not inconceivable that some day we will have molecular sieves that can preferentially trap sodium ions while rejecting bigger species.  You could then add some of these magic beads to your soup, stir for 10 minutes and scoop them out, carrying the salt (assuming the soup is not too thick).  I doubt taste would be unaffected, though.  Your soup would taste sour since you'd be replacing $\ce{Na^+}$ with, presumably, $\ce{H^+}$; even if most of these got attached to bases you'd still be lowering the pH.  In any case I know of no such technology at present.

Comment: Great information! It would be nice if more chemists and food chemists could complain to Campbells soup , Knorr soup ,Healthy-choice soup, and a whole lot of other product about the amount of sodium in the product that can't be gotten rid of. Isn't it true if most people cut down their sodium levels from processed food A LOT  of money would be saved in healthcare costs?

Comment: Taste will be affected a lot even if we weren't replacing the ions. The reason why this salt is put in is for taste. The soup will taste bland without the sodium, and even if we had some magic method of making it disappear without a trace, the taste will change a lot.